# Insert data in the table with timezone info

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql with the timezone info. I am able to achieve this with column type as TIMESTAMPTZ in postgresql but with mysql I am unable to achieve the same.

I have created mysql table with below command

```
CREATE TABLE idvalue(id INTEGER NOT NULL, time TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, value DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL);
```

so mysql is storing time value as `2020-06-18 11:02:29.295868` however in postgresql it store as `2020-06-18 11:02:29.295868+05:30`. Is there any way I could achieve this apart from storing the column as string?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will store `timestamp` in `UTC`. 
It will convert your timestamp to UTC before storing and will convert back when you retrieve it. It will use timezone set by `time_zone` variable.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: I was hoping mysql had a way to store time semantically right way (http://cldr.unicode.org/development/development-process/design-proposals/time-zone-offset-patterns) like +00:00 or 'Z' option which suggest the time is stored as UTC.

Comment: I don't know why do you need to have timezone information stored, but you can store it separately or store the whole date as `varchar` with your own notation.